# How to load an image and resize it immediately to use later

Tags: android

I am working on an app for image processing.
I use BitmapFactory.decodeStream to load an image, when I press the button to pass the image to setPixel, it leads to OutOfMemoryError.
I tried smaller image is okay.

Anyway to load a big image and immediately save it in Bitmap with a smaller size?

Answer (score 2):

Use `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` to decode a smaller bitmap.

> `public int inSampleSize`
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original
>   image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is
>   the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single
>   pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, `inSampleSize == 4` returns an
>   image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the
>   number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the
>   decoder will try to fulfill this request, but the resulting bitmap may
>   have different dimensions that precisely what has been requested.
>   Also, powers of 2 are often faster/easier for the decoder to honor.