# how to show zoomed part of image and drag the image to left, right ,top ,bottom on touch of image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I need to show zoomed part of an image and the image should move to left, right, top, bottom when image is dragged(touched) accrodingly.

I am using imageview for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/imageView2">
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help. how can i do this?

Thanks
Jyoti

Comment: please provide some code what are you tried?

Comment: "I need to show zoomed part of an image"? means?

Comment: i need to show only centre part of an image at first time. then the image should be moved to left, right, top, bottom on touch of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
1. Draw your image on canvas..

2. scale the canvas for zoom in - zoom put.
```

EDIT: try this..

```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.graphics.Canvas;
   import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;
   import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
   import android.view.View;

    public class MyImageView extends View {

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

private Drawable mImage;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public MyImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
mImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagename);

    mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(), mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());
}

public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
        if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;

            invalidate();
        }

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    Log.d("DEBUG", "X: "+mPosX+" Y: "+mPosY);
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mImage.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

to call this in your activity,setContentView(new MyImageView(this));

EDIT: [zooming and dragging images using matrix in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881778/zooming-and-dragging-images-using-matrix-in-android) And for zoom /resize the image look at my answer on [How to load an image and resize it immediately to use later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267686/how-to-load-an-image-and-resize-it-immediately-to-use-later/7267885#7267885).

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use a customized view, and draw bitmap(left, top, right, bottom) on the canvas.